# How to position a div between divs

Tags: css, html, tumblr

I was making a theme for my tumblr (not very good at it) & I need help positioning the toplinkss div on top of everything EXCEPT the image that is in the div class header. Can someone pls help. It would be greatly appreciated. I've tried clear:both, z-index, & so many other things. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong so heres the link to the coding.

http://pastebin.com/37R14ia8

Comment: Can you use jsfiddle?  Also, just post the relevant code, I had a eek at the pastbins and my eyes glazed over :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header-Container you have: `position:relati e;` There's an v missing. Check if that happened somewhere else too.

If you fix this and add a position to every container you wanna z-index. Adding a z-index should work without a problem then.